# How can I import visuals as vs?

Tags: python

When I try to import supplementary visualizations code I got the following:

```
import visuals as vs

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'visuals'**
```

I tried to install VPython via the link: https://vpython.org/presentation2018/install.html
and then:

```
conda install -c vpython vpython
```

but I got error:

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/vpython/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https://conda.anaconda.org/vpython/win-64'
```

I tried again and again but it did not work.

My second try was:

```
pip install vpython
```

but I got 'ERROR: No matching distribution found for vpython.'

Do you have any advise how can I import visuals as vs?

Thanks,

Comment: From the [docs](https://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/index.html): _be aware that for the current version of VPython the name of the module is "vpython", not "visual"_

Comment: I was able to install it here with pip via `pip install vpython`. What version of python are you using?

Comment: Python 3.8(32bit)

Answer (score 0):

If it's python version 3.8, try using pip3 install vpython

Comment: For the answer to be more useful, please include why pip3 should be used, maybe a link to the documentation, etc. So that people can understand why you are suggesting this and how it could resolve the issue.